# Is there an easy way to track quality of code in my xcode project for ios?

Tags: ios, xcode, quality

I really need to confirm with independent tool very bad quality of code in one of ios projects written in swift.

- Is there any tool for this?
- how it works?

Comment: first you have to define what's code quality.

Answer (score 5):

**[Swift-Clean](http://swiftcleanapp.com)**

An OS X app that works with Xcode to keep your Swift code clean. Swift-Clean takes the answers you give to a short survey on Swift coding style and creates a configuration file. The Mac app then uses this to either fix errors automatically or create build warnings if it can't. Once you've completed the survey, you can not only download your own configuration file, but you can also choose from the average of all responses or the Stack Overflow results.

---

**[Taylor](https://github.com/yopeso/Taylor)**

A tool that aims to improve Swift code quality, by checking for conformance of code metrics. Unlike similar linting tools, Taylor focuses on more subjective code quality metric by providing warnings for rules such as excessive class or method length, too many overly complicated methods, excessive block depth or too many method parameters. It can be run independently from the command line on a single file or a complete project, or you can add a build phase to add warnings to Xcode.